# 6 DOF detection using multiple goodfeaturetotrack points on openCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, tracking

I am currently working on a head motion tracking project using normal webcam. Face detection and LK tracking works fine but hope to build something more comprehensive. Is it possible to use the coordinates of the feature points in one frame to the next to estimate the 6 DOF (scaling, rotation) motion of a subject? Intuitively I think it is possible because we can assume that the feature points on all the frames fall on the same plane. I am looking to measure the pitch yaw and roll and scaling of the subject. Scaling is easy if we assume that the subject only experience translation (no pitch yaw roll) by just looking at the different in distance between any two given feature points. Pitch yaw roll and scaling becomes tricky when they all combine. I am trying to find out how Kinect capture motion because my guess is I can treat the feature points like the infra red pattern for Kinect.

Please advice on this. Need to find out the feasibility of this method before I try something else.

THanks,
Kelvin

Comment: Seems like either solvePNP or POSIT is good enough. But since solvePNP can deal with coplanar points, I think solvePNP is a better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't completely advise on the feasibility of what you propose, because then it depends on your feature extraction method, i.e. how do you get your feature points?  If your subject always faces the camera, then you can apply active appearance models for head pose estimation which will tell you the position of a statistically computed 3d face mesh fit to a new facial image. A guy called Pedro Martins did a lot of work on this including AAM+POSIT tracking and head-pose estimation http://www2.isr.uc.pt/~pedromartins/ Myself I also used AAMs for extracting facial expressions, which, as a problem, requires more individual facial feature tracking accuracy then the 6 DOF. For AAM, besides it's tracking application literature, there exist a lot of open-source implementations as well including the one of Pedro Martins himself for pose estimation.

However, as I wrote all above I realised that you might not have the case of head facing the camera thus making AAMs of less use. How does your data look like? Do you have a sample video?

P.S. As for Kinect-I don't know the conditions of your project but Kinect 2 is going to have a sufficient resolution will track the full face mesh, but it's released in next year. Generally, I hope someone can give a more experienced answer to head tracking problem with rotation/scaling estimation.

Comment: Hi Leonid thanks for the comment.I am using a combination of Haas cascade for eyes, nose and mouth,and also good features to track as my feature points. I set the z coordinate of these points on a very simplistic model (i.e anything on mouth is co planar). It works ok for now but I have issues with facial expressions like movement of mouth of eyes. I am looking for a more accurate model that can take care of this. Essentially what I hope to get is to track a region of interest on the face from frame to frame,and measure the translation and rotation of the face. If u have any ideas let me know.